# Alter method signature for child class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

In the example below (Typescript, 1.7+), what would I have to change to allow `B.callback` to have a different signature than `A.callback`?

```
class A {
    callback(result: number) {
    }
}


class B extends A {
    callback(result: number, option: number) {
    }
}
```

Currently this gives `test.ts(7,7): error TS2415: Class 'B' incorrectly extends base class 'A'.`

In the real world my example is more complex, but I can dynamically  (more or less) *guarantee* (based on some configuration) that the requested parameters will be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the situation, the following solution may suffice too:

```
class A {
    callback(result: number) {
    }
}


class B extends A {
    callback(result: number, option?: number) { // make 'option' optional
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will never be allowed. You need to conform to the base class function signature because its *polymorphism 101*:

```
class A {
    callback(result: number) {
    }
}


class B extends A {
    callback(result: number, option?: number) {
    }
}

// Reason
var b = new B();
var a:A = b; // okay as its a subclass
a.callback(123); // If b didn't have that optional B.callback can blow up
```

Comment: Well, yes, but one could argue that any parameter could be undefined at any time nonetheless, so `a.callback(123)` would still be a valid method call to `b`.

Comment: `would still be a valid method call to b` Explicitly passing `undefined` is different from an implicit undefined. And if you find yourself passing an explicit undefined ... please consider making it an optional argument

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not possible in TypeScript 1.6 and the upcoming 1.7. Either give `B.callback()` a new name, or add the parameter as an optional parameter in `A.callback()`.

It feels kind of wrong from a traditional OOP standpoint, i.e. C#, Java. One should not be able to change the number of parameters in an overridden method. A reference to class `A` is be able to hold class `B` objects. If `B` adds a non-optional parameter to a method, calls to the method via the `A` reference would fail. This would be raised as an error by the compiler.

Comment: From a traditional standpoint I'm with you. In my example though `callback` is passed into Angular (as a controller), and dynamically receives a number of parameters based on its configuration (which is set in B's `constructor()`).

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth I think the best solution is currently:

```
class A {
    callback(result: number, ...rest: any[]) {
    }
}


class B extends A {
    callback(result: number, option: number) {
    }
}
```